# [Easy|Power]Mock: make constructor.newInstance(...) throw an exception?

Tags: java, exception, junit, constructor, mocking

I want to make `constructor.newInstance(...)` throw an exception in a unit test. I'd like to check if the else-branch is reached in the following (dummy-)code:

```java
public <T extends IInterface> instantiate(final Constructor<IInterface> constructor) {
    try {
        return constructor.newInstance(arg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'd like to reach the `null` case. Can I mock that **without** using (Power)Mockito?

I could theoretically do

```java
class TestImplementation implements IInterface {
    public TestImplementation(Arg.class) {
        throw new InstantiationException("just for your test case");
    }
}
```

But I'm curious whether or not I can achieve this with mocking.

Comment: you could pass arguments that would cause an exception, otherwise, mock it, that's what mocking is for

Comment: And just for the record: consider returning `Optional<IInterface>` to avoid returning null! Bonus hint: don't use "hungarian" notation, like IInterface in java. Use meaningful names, and don't burden readers with such details (that shouldnt matter that way in 2019).

Comment: Why are you using `constructor.newInstance` instead of `Function<Arg,T>`?

Comment: @chrylis: I'm testing someone else's code, and that's the argument that gets passed. How can I use `Function<Arg,T>` in place of a constructor? (arg does not get passed to the method)

Comment: @GhostCat: Hungarian notation just brevity

Comment: @manavortex You're using `arg` in your example method, so clearly you have access to it, and when a class has a single-argument constructor, `SomeClass::new` is a valid parameter for `Function<Arg,I>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `java.lang.Constructor` is final, so mocking is hard by default. The latest versions of Mockito support mocking final classes, EasyMock does not to my knowledge.

Thus, your choices are probably:

- Mockito (latest versions, with the new experimental "mocking of final" enabled)
- PowerMock(ito)
- JMockit

And for the record: passing in a Class instance of some "dummy" class, like you suggest within the question is **way better** than using a mocking framework.

You have to understand: you don't use mocking because you *can*. You only use it when you *have* to! In your case, there is a simple, straight forward non-mocking solution to test your production code.

So: use `TestImplementation.class` and forget about using a mocking framework here.